# How to prove formally that $x=y²$ is the inverse relation of $y=x²$?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

I think that , in general, one can find the inverse relation of a function $y = f(x)$ by exchanging $x$'s and $y$'s places, which gives : $x = f(y)$.

Note : I'm not talking of " inverse function" but simply of " inverse relation". I do not ask for a relation that would necessarily be also a function.

But how to prove formally that this method is correct?

In particular, how to prove formally that the inverse relation of

$\{ (x,y) \mid y = x² \} $

is

$\{ (x,y) \mid x = y² \} $?

How to prove that the ordered pairs belonging to the second relation are the inversed couples of the first relation?

A desired proof would look like this . It would begin with

Inverse of R = { (y,x) | y= f(x) }

and end with

Inverse of R = { (x,y) | x = f(y)} .

My question is : what syntactical "manoeuvres" allow to exchange x's and y's place on the right of the vertical bar?

Comment: Call the first $R$ and the second $S$. If $(a,b)\in R$, then it is of the form $(a,a^2)$, but its inverse $(a^2,a)$  is the element of $S$ satisfying the condition in $S$ for $x=a^2$ and $y=a$. Conversely, if $(a,b)$ is in $S$, then it is of the form $(b^2,b)$. Then, its inverse $(b,b^2)$ is in $R$, since it satisfies the condition in $R$, for $x=b$ and $y=b^2$.

Comment: @Sebastiano. - I simply want the new relation to be the inverse relation of the original one. It is not required the new relation to be also a function.

Comment: "Inverse of R = { (y,x) | y= f(x) }

and end with

Inverse of R = { (x,y) | x = f(y)} . " Variables are only place holders:  So  $\{ (y,x) | y= f(x) \} = \{(goomichewybot, frenchdoorwaffles)|frenchdoorwaffles = goomichewybot^2\}=\{(x,y)|x=f(y)\}$.  That's *all* there is to it.  You can simply claime $\{ (y,x) | y= f(x) \} = \{(x,y)|x=f(y)\}$ without proof. Or if you want a trivial proof $(a,b)\in\{(y,x)|y=f(x)\}\iff b=f(a) \iff (a,b)\in \{(x,y)|x=f(y)\}$. So $\{(y,x)|y=f(x)\}=  \{(x,y)|x=f(y)\}$.

Comment: @fleablodd. Thanks. This is helpful!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need a *definition* of what an inverse function is.  Then it's almost certain $y=x^2$ fits the definition.

Actually I suppose we also have to know what you mean when you say $x= y^2$ or $y=x^2$ is a relation.

=====

> Definition 1: A relation $R$ on a set $A$ is a subset of $A\times A$..... period.  And we say $aRb$ if $(a,b) \in R$.

When you say $x=y^2$ is a relation you are referring to a set $\{(x,y)| x= y^2\} \subset \mathbb R\times \mathbb R$.  We can call that set/relation $R$. And when we refer to $y=x^2$ as a relation we are referring to the set, $\{(x,y)| y = x^2\}$.  We can call that set $S$.

Now we need a definition of "inverse relation".  I'm not sure what your text uses but I think a definition would be

> Definiton 2: $R^{-1}$ is the inverse of $R\subset \mathbb R\times \mathbb R$ if for any $a, b\in A$ then $(a,b) \in R\iff (b,a) \in R^{-1}$....
>
> .. or alternatively.   $R^{-1} = \{(b,a)| (a,b) \in R\}$.

=======

Now the proof should be straight forward:

If $R = \{(x,y)\in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R|x=y^2\}$ and $S=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R|y=x^2\}$ then

$x=y^2 \iff (x,y) \in \{(x,y) \in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R|x = y^2\} = R$.

$x=y^2 \iff (y,x) \in \{(y,x) \in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R|x = y^2\} =\{(w,z)\in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R|z=w^2\} =\{(x,y)\in \mathbb R\times \mathbb R|y=x^2\}=S$ (variables are nothing but place holders)

So $R^{-1} = S$.

Answer (score 1):

It's very simple: the inverse relation of a relation $\mathcal R=\{(x,y\}\subset X\times Y$ is just the relation $\mathcal R^{-1}=\{(y,x)\in Y\times X\mid (x,y)\in \mathcal R\}$.

Therefore, if your relation is $\mathcal R=\{(x, x^2)\mid x\in\mathbf R\}$, the inverse relation is $\mathcal R^{-1}=\{(x^2,x)\mid x\in\mathbf R\}$.

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to prove it without practicing the inversion at the variables level ( before the vertical bar in the set builder notation)  but inside the defining formula itself ( after the vertical bar).  I know that writing " the set of all (x, x²) ..."  is usually done, but I would like a proof strictly respecting the syntax of set theory.

Comment: In other words, could you please give a proof that would be a strict application of the definition you gave of " inverse relation". Purely formal and syntactic, without implicit understanding ( as I think it is the case when one writes ( x, x²) or ( x², x)   ).

Comment: It consists in observing that, if you *generically* denote $(x,y)$ an element of any  relation, the element $(\xi^2,\xi)\in\mathcal R^{-1}$ satisfies  $x=y^2$.